# NumberFormatException in linked list implementation

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I implemented a circular list in Java. The code asks for the `int` values to be entered, and I wish to terminate the input list with an `"END"`. The code works but throws a runtime exception: `NumberFormatException`.

```
try{
    while(true){
        newnode=new Node();
        oldnode.next=newnode;
        newnode.prev=oldnode;               
        System.out.print("Enter value:");
        try{
            ctrlstr=bfr.readLine();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (ctrlstr=="END") break;
        newnode.val=Integer.parseInt(ctrlstr);
        oldnode=newnode;                        
        i++;    
    }
}
catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What's the question? When does it throw a NumberFormatException?

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
if (ctrlstr=="END")
```

you're comparing strings using `==`, which always checks for reference identity. Instead, you should use `equals`:

```
if (ctrlstr.equals("END"))
```

or perhaps (if you want just a `false` result when `ctrlstr` is null)

```
if ("END".equals(ctrlstr))
```

A few extra notes:

- Catching `Exception` is usually a bad idea - you should catch more specific exceptions
- Catching an exception and then continuing anyway after printing it is usually a bad idea
- Your code will be more readable if you indent appropriately
- Your code will be more readable if you *always* use braces for `if` statements etc

Comment: hey jon.....thanks a lot...and i do mean it! it had been bogging me down for quite some time... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try
      `ctrlstr.equals("END")` instead.